# Refactoring CSS Using PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I have the following CSS div / class mark-up

```
.myclass #myid{
    width: ;
    height: ;
}
```

This is in about a dozen CSS files.  Each CSS file has different widths and heights defined.  I'd like to replace all of the markup in each file with a single consistent mark-up.  Something like this

```
.myclass #myid{
    width: 20px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Is this possible with PHPStorm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes -- it's possible to find such **exact matches** (specific selector that has "width" and "height" properties defined in that order). You just need some rather basic knowledge of **regular expressions**.

1. Use "Replace In Path" dialog (Edit | Find | Replace in Path <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+R</kbd>)
2. Activate "Regular Expression" option
3. Set correct scope (Whole Project or specific scope/folder/etc)
4. Type your regular expressions:

   - Text to find: `(\.myclass \#myid\s*\{\n\s*width:\s*)\d+(px;\n\s*height:\s*)\d+(px;)`
   - Replace with: `$122$233$3`
5. Hit the button

**NOTES:**

- The regex for "replace with" will set "width" to 22 and "height" to 33 -- edit them as required.
- Same with "text to find" regex -- the one which I write will not find if you write something like `width: 0;` ("px" unit is omitted). I've built it based on your example, so if it differs you will have to adjust it yourself.
- That regex will not work if you have any other property before "width" .. or in different order.

[image]